# IBM Watson Studio- Cloud Object Storage

Tags: websphere, ibm-watson

Can someone help me. I have a Lite plan in IBM Watson Studio and I want to create new project but when I try to add storage I got an error "[409, Conflict] LITE_PLAN_LIMIT". Please someone help me. I am currently enrolled in a course and I can't continue because of this problem

Comment: You say *I am currently enrolled in a course*, contact your mentor or teacher.  Looks like you hit some resources limit, and we can't do anything about it from here...

Answer (score 0):

The Lite plan of Watson Studio include 50 capacity hours per month:

https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/watson-studio

```
0 capacity unit-hours monthly limit
Environment = # of capacity units required per hour
• 1 vCPU + 4 GB RAM = 0.5
• 2 vCPU + 8 GB RAM = 1
• 4 vCPU + 16 GB RAM = 2
• Decision Optimization = Environment + 5
```

You can upgrade to the Standard plan (for a fee,) create another IBM Cloud account and spin up another Watson Studio lite instance, wait a month for the capacity to reset, or ask your instructor for a feature code that will give you more resources.